# Efficient stdin generation in shell script

Tags: xargs, shell-builtin

Is there a more idiomatic way to express the following?

```
xargs -r -l1 -I % bash -c 'cat <(echo %)'
```

Where `cat` stands for intended program that does not accept relevant argument from command line, like `batch`.

Comment: `-I` mplies -x and -L 1

Answer (score 2):

The shell's `read` builtin is usually not very fast (to put it very politely) but this may save several forks:

```
while read line; do
    echo -n "$line" | cat /dev/stdin
done
```

Comment: `echo -n` is not reliable (some versions of `echo` just print "-n" as output); also, if I understand right, the linefeed shouldn't be skipped anyway. Also, if you're using bash (not a generic shell), and *do* want the linefeed, you can replace the `echo` with `cat /dev/stdin <<<"$line"`; this cuts it from two forks per line to just one.